# Ensuring that Javascript functions and callbacks are executed in the correct order

Tags: javascript, callback, timing

I have a page with the below setup. I'm having issues with timing because I'm calling a function, defined later in the body, from a callback in the header. I need to make sure that `doSomething(stuff)` is only executed once `myScript.js` and the final script tag are evaluated.

Some things I've tried:

- using `window.onload` - there's no guarantee that the callback will be executed before the window finishes loading.
- using `setTimeout` to make sure doSomething is defined, and continue trying it until it's defined. This works, but I worry that on slow connections or a busy page it will take a long time and be blocking.
- defining `doSomething` in the header as well and using it only to assign the variable to access later in the body (I posted code below to show this option)

What setup should I use to correctly make sure that all of the code on the page is executed in the correct order, and as quickly as possible?

---

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myQueue = [];
    myQueue.push(function(){
        getSomeStuff({
             timeout: 4000,
             gotStuffCallback: function(stuff){
                doSomething(stuff);
             }
        })
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- a script that takes an undetermined amount of time to execute -->
<script src="myScript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var doSomething = function(stuff){
        // uses code from the external js file myScript.js
        useMyScript(stuff);
    };
</script>
</body>
```

---

Code for the third option:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myQueue = [];

    var headerStuff;
    var doSomething = function(stuff){
        headerStuff = stuff;
    }

    myQueue.push(function(){
        getSomeStuff({
             timeout: 4000,
             gotStuffCallback: function(stuff){
                doSomething(stuff);
             }
        })
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- a script that takes an undetermined amount of time to execute -->
<script src="myScript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var doSomething = function(stuff){
        var stuff = headerStuff || stuff;
        // uses code from the external js file myScript.js
        useMyScript(stuff);
    };
</script>
</body>
```

Edit: added missing `var` in front of `myQueue`.

Comment: myScript tag is mandatory to be on the body of the document?

Comment: Not necessarily, but since it might take a while to execute I'd like to put it as late on the page as possible.

Comment: Where is `myQueue` started?

Comment: No, your "third option" code does not work.

Comment: @Bergi if you could give me some guidance on how to fix option 3 that would be great. I hadn't actually implemented it, I just wrote the code above to show the kind of thing I was thinking of. And apologies, I just forgot the var, post edited.

Comment: Do you have access to myScript? Is yours? Set a global variable inside of it attached to the window object and check for its existence before running useMyScript(). Put a setinterval and clear it when that var is defined.

Comment: I don't have access to myScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use promises and there is no reason that you can not (you can always polyfill with bluebird).

You could create a promise at the the head of your html, with continuation as callbacks and resolve it in the last javascript block.

Here goes:

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var trigger;
    alert('start')
     new Promise(function(resolve) {
        trigger = resolve;
      })
      .then(
        function() {
          // call your callback here
          alert('callback');
        });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- here goes your long runing script -->

  <script>
    alert('finish');
    trigger();
  </script>
</body>
```